# Get stuck on family tree using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

There is a family tree and I want to get the relation of two persons.
For example,

[image]

getOneAncestry(Chaos, Uranus) returns "Uranus born of Gaia born of Chaos"

Now I have this: (I only copy part of my code, hope others will not affect)
'''

```
    static class Individual {
    public String name;
    
    public Individual[] children;

    public Individual(String name, Individual[] children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
    }

    boolean noChildren(){
        if (this.children == null){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    String  getOneAncestor(Individual parent, String children){
        //if ancestor has no child
        if (parent.noChildren()){
            return null;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
            if (parent.children[i].name.equalsIgnoreCase(children)){
                return parent.children[i].name + " born of " + parent.toString();
            }else{
                getOneAncestor(parent.children[i], children);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

'''
I'm stuck on the getOneAncestry(), I know I should use recursion, but I can't resolve it.
So anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using recursion you need to do something with the result and return a value accordingly otherwise nothing will happen. In the code below we use the return statement to make a chain of people between the ancestor and the descendant. I have annotated what additional steps need to be taken in the code below. The key part is `String result = getOneAncestor(...)` and `return result + " born of " + ancestor.name;` as shown here:

```
//Input args renamed to keep it simple and clear
String  getOneAncestor(Individual ancestor, String descendant){
    //You can remove this check, the null return after the for loop takes care of this
    //if (ancestor.noChildren()){
    //    return null;
    //}

    for (int i = 0; i < ancestor.children.length; i++) {
        //Check to find the descendant
        if (ancestor.children[i].name.equalsIgnoreCase(descendant)){
            //when the descendant is found then return their name
            //The below recursive method inside the else statement will take care of the " born of " part
            return ancestor.children[i].name;
        }
        //Otherwise check the children's children for a match
        else{
            //Get the return of the recursive method so that you can do something with it
            String result = getOneAncestor(ancestor.children[i], descendant);
            
            //If a match is found in one of the children (not null returned)
            //Then we can append the " bourn of " text and return the result
            if (result != null){
                //Add the in-between relation and return the string of all relations so far in the tree
                return result + " born of " + ancestor.name;
            }
        }
    }
    //Return null if no match found within the generation
    //Or if the ancestor has no children
    return null;
}
```

Comment: But actually, in the if statement the return value should contains " born of ". I don't know why but just run the test, it shows so

Comment: The bourn of part does not need to be added when the descendant is found because we don't know who the ancestor is yet, instead the else statment adds the born of part when the child is returned to the previous recursive call. Does it work correctly when you run the code?